# trouble in emitting <AgGridReact> , using clojurescript + Reagent + cljsjs/ag-grid-react

Tags: clojurescript, reagent, clojurescript-javascript-interop

I'm trying to use React `ag-grid` in Reagent ([ag-grid reference](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-getting-started/)) , but having trouble in emitting  `node AgGridReact` ,

Implemented React.Component using [pesterhazy](https://gist.github.com/pesterhazy/2a25c82db0519a28e415b40481f84554) approach , but emitting  `AgGridReact` from rendor method is not working. Please suggest a better way with hiccup syntax ,

I was checking something like this from the render method:

```
(def ag-adapter (reagent/adapt-react-class js/agGridReact))

 [ag-adapter {  columnDefs={somecols}  rowData={somerowData}}]
```

FYI, I created the project using the command `lein new reagent reagent-aggrid`, and using `lein figwheel` grid reference `[cljsjs/ag-grid-react "17.0.0-0"]`

*********UPDATE :**

Got this resolved using below , sample [reagent-aggrid](https://github.com/mohankumarcm/cs/tree/master/reagent-aggrid)

```
(def ag-adapter (reagent/adapt-react-class (.-AgGridReact js/agGridReact) ))
```

Comment: got this resolved using below , sample reagent-aggrid

(def ag-adapter (reagent/adapt-react-class (.-AgGridReact js/agGridReact) ))

Comment: You can answer your own question, and even accept your own answer.

Comment: thanks smith , for formatting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got this resolved using below , issue was with the way I referred ag grid

```
(def ag-adapter (reagent/adapt-react-class (.-AgGridReact js/agGridReact) ))
```